# I can't add FreiChat.V.9.6 with latest version of Joomla

Tags: joomla

http://codologic.com/forum/index.php?u=/serve/attachment&path=53a3efb4555f2.gif

I had uploaded the FreiChat.V.9.6.zip file to the Joomla base folder. Then I had visited the URL http://socialphobians.oo3.co/freichat but I'm getting the error message.

"The requested page cannot be found.
An error has occurred while processing your request.

You may not be able to visit this page because of:

an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a mistyped address
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
you have no access to this page
Go to the Home Page

If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.

404 Category not found"

I have also tried socialphobians.oo3.co/freichat/installation/index.php

**What I have to do next?**

1. Is my .htaccess and .htaccess.preinstall files blocking anything? If "yes" then please give me a working .htaccess file. [Please note that I had not modify anything on the htaccess and .htaccess.preinstall files]

There is no restriction to access the freichat folder.

1. Do I have to upload the "Freichat" in a different directory instead of the home (base) directory?
2. Anything else?

Comment: You should be asking this on the Frechat forums or contacting the developer via email as it's regarding a 3rd party extension.

Comment: I already posted this on Frechat as well Joomla forum but I didn't get any response yet!

Answer (score 0):

you have not uploaded the freichat folder in the correct location.

or there is some misconfiguration in the .htaccess file

Comment: I had uploaded the freichat folder in Joomla by this tutorial and its working for him! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXya4TuX7Ro

Comment: [image](http://codologic.com/forum/index.php?u=/serve/attachment&path=53a3efb4555f2.gif)